# Add a resizable handle to the top of a div with position fixed bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I make a div that is fixed position bottom expand from a handle on its top?

If you look at the StackOverflow question form, it has an expandable handle on the bottom, how can I place such a handle on the top of a `div`?

jquery-ui's resizable does not appear to support this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/725/.

A none jquery solution is fine.

Comment: Alright this is the closest I've gotten - written from scratch with jquery - http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/728/

Comment: If you're going to downvote, leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html:

```
<div id="container" class="resizable">
    <div id="handle" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resizable").resizable({
        handles: {
            'n': '#handle'
        }
    });
});
```

Css:

```
body {
    height: 1000px;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#handle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    top: -6px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/732/

Comment: It's not positioned to the bottom anymore

Comment: I'm sorry. You didn't say it should be at the bottom. In the first Fiddle you provided it was at the top. Or actually you had the wrong selector class so it wasn't showing at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/724/